# Encoding characters

Tags: wordpress, encoding

I’ve got a probleme in my different pages.
Some caracters don’t display the correct encoding.

If you go to this page : https://www.fracbretagne.fr/fr/presentation/le-frac-bretagne then in the first part, you see the problem.

For example, in the text "internationales, décloisonné en s’ouvrant à d’autres champs disciplinaires, inscrit".

The s haven’t the good display, there is a comma below the s therefore there isn’t a comma in french alaphabet.

How to change and put the correct encoding ?
Thanks and regards.

Comment: You need to convert your database in UTF 8, and define it in wordpress. [link](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480)

Comment: Thank for your answer. My database have different collations. If i understand good, i must change all the collation with UTF8 ?

Comment: When i imported my database, i select UTF 8. There is no change, caracters don't display the good encoding

Comment: and in Wordpress ? Have you restart the Wordpress engine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from the page encoding which is well appropriate for *le français*.

It comes from the font face `Heebo` which is a Hebrew and Latin typeface family.

If you look at https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Heebo in Glyphs section you won't find our beloved special characters éèà...

You shall replace default font face in your theme from Heebo to Roboto since Heebo is a Hebrew and Latin typeface family, which extends Christian Roberton's Roboto Latin to Hebrew.

Comment: Thank you Gael ! :)

Comment: De rien, Kenavo !